# Raven DB patch request not running on start

Tags: ravendb

I currently have a ravenDB database with a model that has a specific set of fields that I have been working with. I realized there is a field or two that I need to add and have successfully used ravenDB's patch request once to patch my documents in my database to initialize those fields on all the pre existing documents. I wanted to add another field again but I cannot get the patch code to run again to update my documents another time. I was wondering if someone could tell me if there was any documentation or methods to check the database at deploy and see if the models are the same, if not to patch the ones that are not but leave the ones that are alone and ensure after an update the pre existing models are not reset to what the patch is patching.

```
private void updateDb(IDocumentStore store)
    {
        store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Interviews_ByCandidateInterviewAndDate", 
            new IndexQuery{
                Query = "Candidate:"
            }, 
            new []{
                new PatchRequest{
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                    Name = "IsArchived",
                    Value = true
                },
                new PatchRequest{
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                    Name = "ArchiveDate",
                    Value = null
                },
                new PatchRequest{
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                    Name = "TestingField",
                    Value = 14
                }
            },
            new BulkOperationOptions
            {
                AllowStale = false
            }
        );
    }
```

The first two patch requests went through and shows up in the database but one thing I cannot see is if i were to run this patch again to get that third field into the model, would it change all the values that are already existing in the database for the first two to true and null or would it leave them the way they are and more importantly, I cannot get this code to run again.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You query is wrong:

```
            Query = "Candidate:"
```

Should have no results (invalid query).

Use:

```
            Query = "Candidate:*"
```